# Flutter, How to display scrollable tab bar in the center of the screen, below the content and have it display the icon and its content

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, frontend

I want to create a scrollable tab bar in the center of the screen. It works but the icon on the tabbar aren't showing up. How to fix this? How to make it works? I've tried to ask chatgpt but it doesn't give a best answer for that..

this is my code, I tried putting the icon in a row widget, but it still didn't work:

```
class DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 60,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.chevron_back, color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
          title: const Text("Back"),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/aurora-background.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 90, left: 30, right: 30),
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: const Icon(
                          CupertinoIcons.power,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  _dateCard(dap: widget.dap),
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Container(
                    height: 135,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: _temperatureCard(water: widget.water, air: widget.air),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 20,),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: _humidityCard(humidity: widget.humidity),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  _heaterFanControl(),
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 50,
                            child: AppBar(
                              bottom: TabBar(
                                tabs: [
                                  Tab(
                                    icon: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(Icons.directions_bike_rounded),
                                        SizedBox(width: 8),
                                        Text('Bike'),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Tab(
                                    icon: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                                        SizedBox(width: 8),
                                        Text('Car'),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TabBarView(
                              children: [
                                // first tab bar view widget
                                Container(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Bike',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),

                                // second tab bar view widget
                                Container(
                                  color: Colors.pink,
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Car',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the result:
[screenshot of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waHbB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I removed the app bar widget and used preferred height; it works for me:

```
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                child: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: TabBar(
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.directions_bike,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of the fixed layout]